# Find duplicates inside object in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an String in kibana inside "message" field that contains and unique id which is called "uniqueKey", i would like to know how can i filter it to get all documents where the field value is duplicating whitout knowing its exactly value

```
2023-01-13 11:01:47.161 DEBUG 1 --- [] i.s.EventProcessor      : Received event '{"type":"MYEVENT","eventData":{"created":"2023-01-13T11:01:47+00:00","user":**"uniqueKey":"ab9c4820933111ed85654f402a6693ed"**}' with headers '{amqp_deliveryTag=33, content-type=application/json, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode, timestamp=1673607707161}'
```

I want to get all documents that are repeating this key

UPDATE 1:
Below are a full log in JSON format

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-6.8.23-2023.01.13",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "OqlPq4UBF4YD0y9eW8gi",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2023-01-13T13:26:10.398Z",
    },
    "kubernetes": {
      "pod": {
        "name": "my-ms",
        "uid": "d34548f3d"
      },
      "container": {
        "name": "my-ms",
        "image": "docker2.company.com/my-ms"
      },
    },
    "beat": {
      "version": "6.8.23",
      "name": "filebeat-sqhtm",
      "hostname": "filebeat-sqhtm"
    },
    "host": {
      "name": "filebeat-sqhtm"
    },
    "offset": 6772155,
    "stream": "stdout",
    "message": "2023-01-13 11:01:47.161 DEBUG 1 --- [] i.s.EventProcessor      : Received event '{"type":"MYEVENT","eventData":{"created":"2023-01-13T11:01:47+00:00","user":**"uniqueKey":"ab9c4820933111ed85654f402a6693ed"**}' with headers '{amqp_deliveryTag=33, content-type=application/json, contentType=application/x-java-object;type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode, timestamp=1673607707161}'",
    "prospector": {
      "type": "docker"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-01-13T13:26:10.398Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1673616370398
  ]
}
```

Comment: This log seems like raw version which will be sent for ingestion, can you please share a log from Kibana in JSON format? If your event is being parsed as JSON, you should have a field called "uniqueKey" already available.

Comment: @Ayush thanks for your answer. i've updated my question including a full JSON. Unfortunately there is no uniqueKey field in the JSON structure, its in JSON format but inside message field i think as a raw String

Comment: I'd suggest you to create an ingest pipeline to audit your unique key in this case which will be stored as field along with your event. This can be done even from logstash, but you will have to send logs from filebeat to logstash then. Ingest pipeline can work with Java methods, so you should be able to capture the required substring and add it to the ctx.

Comment: @Ayush thanks a lot for the help, i will take a look to your approach.